# ansible - download java jdk - ERROR: multiple actions specified in task: 'command'

Tags: variables, jinja2, roles, ansible

Ansible : 1.9.2 (thus using wget instead of get_url).
Linux CentOS 6.5

Running the following command and getting the following error message:

```
$ ansible-playbook site.yml ${sudo_user_opts} -i hosts -u builduser --private-key ${DEPLOYER_KEY_FILE} --extra-vars "svr_type=${server_type} deploy_environment=${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT} ansible_user=${ANSIBLE_USER}

ERROR: multiple actions specified in task: 'command' and 'Download Java/JDK Versions'
```

Any idea what I'm missing.

Role "java" that I have created has default/main.yml:

```
$ cat roles/java/defaults/main.yml
---
java_versions:
  java7_60:
    version: 1.7.60
    group_path: com/oracle/jdk
    classifier: linux-x64
    ext: tar.gz
    dist_file: "jdk-{{item.value.version }}-{{ item.value.classifier }}-{{ item.value.ext }}"
    dist_url: "{{ artifactory_url }}/{{ item.value.group_path }}/{{ item.value.version }}/{{ dist_file }}"
  java7_67:
    version: 1.7.67
    group_path: com/oracle/jdk
    classifier: linux-x64
    ext: tar.gz
    dist_file: "jdk-{{item.value.version }}-{{ item.value.classifier }}-{{ item.value.ext }}"
    dist_url: "{{ artifactory_url }}/{{ item.value.group_path }}/{{ item.value.version }}/{{ dist_file }}"
  java8_45:
    version: 1.8.45
    group_path: com/oracle/jdk
    classifier: linux-x64
    ext: tar.gz
    dist_file: "jdk-{{item.value.version }}-{{ item.value.classifier }}-{{ item.value.ext }}"
    dist_url: "{{ artifactory_url }}/{{ item.value.group_path }}/{{ item.value.version }}/{{ dist_file }}"
```

Roles some_common has a defaults\main.yml as:

```
---
# common vars
artifactory_url: http://artifactory.company.com:9050/virtual-repos

instance_home: "~"
tools_dir: "{{ instance_home }}/tools"
slaves_dir: "{{ instance_home }}/slaves"
build_user: 'builduser'
build_group: 'build'

common_download_dir: "/tmp"
```

Task inside role: java/tasks/main.yml is:

$ cat roles/java/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- debug: msg="Downloading and installing Java versions - instance_home {{ instance_home }}"

- name: Download Java/JDK Versions
  debug: msg="Java {{ item.key }} is (jdk-{{ item.value.version }}-{{ item.value.classifier }}-{{ item.value.ext }})"
  command: wget -q "{{ item.value.dist_url }}"
    chdir="{{ common_download_dir }}"
    creates="{{ common_download_dir }}/{{ item.value.dist_file }}"
  with_dict: "{{ java_versions }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each task can have only 1 action. The ansible built-in module `debug` counts as an action so you must make it its own separate task like this:

```
- debug: msg="Java {{ item.key }} is (jdk-{{ item.value.version }}-{{ item.value.classifier }}-{{ item.value.ext }})"
  with_dict: "{{ java_versions }}"  

- name: Download Java/JDK Versions
  with_dict: "{{ java_versions }}"  
  command: wget -q "{{ item.value.dist_url }}"
    chdir="{{ common_download_dir }}"
    creates="{{ common_download_dir }}/{{ item.value.dist_file }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. That solved it. Can you help me with this. I wonder if my roles/java/defaults/main.yml is correct ?? After I made the relevant change you mentioned, I'm getting the following error. TASK: [java | Download Java/JDK Versions] *************************************
failed: [server01.poc.jenkins] => (item={'key': 'java7_60', 'value': {'dist_file': u'jdk-{#item.value.version #}-{# item.value.classifier #}-{# item.value.ext #}', 'ext': 'tar.gz', 'version': '1.7.60', 'dist_url': u'{# artifactory_url #}/{# item.value.group_path #}/{# item.value.version #}/{# dist_file #}',

Comment: 'group_path': 'com/oracle/jdk', 'classifier': 'linux-x64'}}) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["wget", "-q", "{# artifactory_url #}/{# item.value.group_path #}/{# item.value.version #}/{# dist_file #}"], "delta": "0:00:00.005900", "end": "2015-11-23 12:36:24.131327", "item": {"key": "java7_60", "value": {"classifier": "linux-x64", "dist_file": "jdk-{#item.value.version #}-{# item.value.classifier #}-{# item.value.ext #}", "dist_url": "{# artifactory_url #}/{# item.value.group_path #}/{# item.value.version #}/{# dist_file #}",

Comment: "ext": "tar.gz", "group_path": "com/oracle/jdk", "version": "1.7.60"}}, "rc": 4, "start": "2015-11-23 12:36:24.125427", "warnings": ["Consider using get_url module rather than running wget"]}

Comment: Opened a new post regarding the same. Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877730/ansible-with-dict-dictionary-how-to-use-variables-defined-in-each-dictionar